# Brackets git giving error

Tags: node.js

I recently started using brackets and just this morning, on starting the IDE, I keep getting a

```
"failed to connect to node.js, extension requires node.js installed"
also - 
"[brackets-git] ExpectedError: max connection attempts reached"
```

But I have node.js installed already. Even ran node--version in command and got the current version I'm using - v0.10.15

PS - I am at work and my internet access is through a HTTP proxy. despite that, throughout last week, it did work. Don't know what's the matter now.

Comment: Solved it. Turns out, proxy affects it and i had to go through internet options to bypass proxy server for local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Turns out, proxy affects it and i had to go through internet options to bypass proxy server for local addresses.